# Make api requests work from another computer on the same network in a react app

Tags: reactjs, express, localhost

I have a react app as well as an express api running on a computer with an ipv4 address of **192.168.1.5**
on ports **3000** & **9000**.

When browsing http://localhost:3000 on that computer, my app works and I can make requests to the api. However when I open the app from another local machine I get the following output:

[image]

And here is base url for making requests in my react app:

[image]

Changing the `baseUrl` to http://192.168.1.5:9000/api makes the app work in my other machine in the same network, but not on the host machine anymore.

So my question is, what do I need to configure to have the app running both on my local computer as well as on another on the same network ?

Comment: to access app on your host use same IP URL instead of `localhost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably have this line in express server

```js
app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Listening"));
```

Pass **`"0.0.0.0"`** as host address.

```js
app.listen(3000, "0.0.0.0");
```

### Make sure that, your Firewall allows the selected port in Inbound rules.

### Also Take a look at [ngrok](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrok). Basically, it exposes your server to the Internet !

Yes, the public internet.

Before starting ngrok service, Start the express server. Pass the server port to ngrok arguments.

```sh
npm install ngrok -g
ngrok http 3000
```

Comment: Using the express-generator, I have the following `var server = http.createServer(app);` I've tried `server.listen(port, '0.0.0.0');` but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you using Windows machine? If yes, turn off firewall if it's enabled. I tried above thing on my Linux machine, And, It works.